# R code for calculation of means of multiple variables conditional on the values of another list of variables

Tags: r

I currently have a dataframe consisting of 17 columns. 10 of the columns have continuous variables and the remaining 7 are binary variables that take values 0 and 1. For each of 10 continuous variables, I wish to calculate the mean, for each case where each of the binary variables equals 0. So I'd like to calculate and store 10*7 =70 means.

How would I do this in R? I have tried using the apply family but am unable to get the desired result. Have replicated my problem below--

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5, nrow = 5))

df$X1 <- c(1:5)
df$X2 <- c(24:28)
df$X3 <- c(5:10)
df$X4 <- rbinom(5, 1, 0.5)
df$X5 <- rbinom(5, 1, 0.5)

#What is the easiest way to list all of the means like below? 
mean1 <- mean(df$X1[which(df$X4==0)])
mean2 <- mean(df$X2[which(df$X4==0)])
mean3 <- mean(df$X3[which(df$X4==0)])
mean4 <- mean(df$X1[which(df$X5==0)])
mean5 <- mean(df$X2[which(df$X5==0)])
mean6 <- mean(df$X3[which(df$X5==0)])

#I have tried--
list1 <- c("df$X1", "df$X2", "df$X3")
list2 <-  c("df$X4", "df$X5")

mapply(mean, list1, list2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
lst1 <- c("X1", "X2", "X3")
lst2 <- c("X4", "X5")
```

one straightforward way is to use nested `sapply`

```
sapply(
  lst1,
  function(i) {
    sapply(
      lst2,
      function(j) mean(df[, i][which(df[, j] == 0)])
    )
  }
)
```

or a compact version

```
t(sapply(lst2,function(k) colMeans(subset(df[lst1],df[,k]==0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In base R, you could use `stack` + `aggregate` as follows:

```
aggregate(.~values + ind, cbind(df[1:3], stack(df[4:5])), mean, subset = values == 0)
  values ind X1 X2 X3
1      0  X4  4 27  9
2      0  X5  3 26  8
```

Compare the results you obtain with the one you have above

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = X4:X5) %>% 
   filter(value == 0) %>% 
   group_by(value, name) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE))
```